# Symfony2 Rookie: Internationalization with special routes and css

Tags: internationalization, symfony

i am currently in the process of learning Symfony2. and i love its cleaniness and professionality

i am wondering what is the easiest way for me to implement this, and make my code easily extendable.

1. my main site should be english `www.mysite.com` , `www.mysite.com/aboutus`, `www.mysite.com/contact`
2. the second site should be arabic, and links reachable under `www.mysite.com/ar, www.mysite.com/ar/aboutus, www.mysite.com/ar/contact`
3. when i click on chosing arabic language, i should be able to chose a different twig template, optimized for `RTL (right to left)`....and special `CSS`....etc

i know i can do this with routing and twig....but i cannot (yet) pinpoint the shortest path  :oops: 
i would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i18n routing, checkout JMS's awesome [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://knpbundles.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).  As for per-language twig templates, there are multiple ways to skin this cat, however the most straightforward would be to create a per-language template file and define that when rendering.  For example:

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    return $this->render("AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.{$this->get('session')->getLocale()}.twig", array('name' => $name));
}
```

Make sure you create both index.html.en.twig and index.html.ar.twig templates.

Comment: sweet answer...thanks man will have a look at bundle and your idea and let you know